# Sorting perl arrays to fixed order

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

HI I have an array with the following keys and values:

```
 atest, 2
 ctest, 3
 btest, 8
 ftest, 1
 gtest, 6
```

and I parse them from a file into an array. Now I want to return them like CSV in that order every time. 
However I can't get this to work.

Source:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl
 use warnings;
 use strict;


 my @data;
 my %tags;
 my $cur_tag;
 my ($tag,$line);
 open (FILE, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die "Could not open file: $!";
 while (<FILE>) {
chomp;
if (/^(MyValStart)/)
    { push @data, {} }
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(atest)\s+(.+)$/)) {
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(ctest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    #print ($line,"\n");
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(itest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(btest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(ytest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(ftest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(gtest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif (  ($tag,$line) = (/^\s*(utest)\S\s+(.+)$/)) {

    $data[-1]{$tag} .= " NEWLINE " if exists $data[-1]{$tag};
    $data[-1]{$tag} .= $line;
    $tags{$tag}++;
    $cur_tag = $tag;
}
elsif ($cur_tag) {
    $data[-1]{$cur_tag} .= " NEWLINE ".$_;
}
 }

 use Text::CSV;
 my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1,auto_diag=>2,eol=>"\n",
sep_char=>";",always_quote=>1,blank_is_undef=>1});
%tags=qw/atest ctest btest ftest gtest/;

$csv->print(select, [%tags]);
for my $row (@data) {
my @vals = map { $row->{$_} } %tags;
$csv->print(select, \@vals);
 }
```

As from the source visible there are also things that I parse into the array that are later not used for the print out. 
Both problems I cannot solve.

The output I want is only for the values of atest, ctest, btest, ftest and gtest in that order like

```
"2"; "3"; "8"; "1"; "6"
"1"; "5"; "2"; "0"; "5"
```

The numbers that are returned can also be words or sentences over multiple lines but that is working already.

The input file is like:

```
 MyValStart
 ---------------

     atest:    2
     ctest:    3
     itest:    3
     btest:    8
     ytest:    3
     ftest:    1
     gtest:    6
     utest:    348385fhjdhgofdgkdfjgd



 MyValStart
 ---------------

     atest:    1
     ctest:    5
     itest:    3
     btest:    2
     ytest:    jfdgdf ifdgijfdjgoksfk iosjfdjdisfpgj
     ftest:    0
     gtest:    5
     utest:    jfsdhgjfd fighfidhg ifhdghfid ifdhjgifdh
```

Any idea on how to fix this so it works correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a corresponding output example for the input example provided cos it's not clear what output you're expecting?

Comment: Re "*I have an array with the following keys and values:*", That doesn't make sense. Array keys are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you're doing this quite a hard way. I'd suggest instead that what you should be doing is reading and parsing your input into sensible data structures, and then outputting those in the desired format.

As you have blocks of 'data' with key-value pairs, and you need to extract named values - an array of hashes would be the tool for the job. Read each 'chunk' into a hash, then insert that into an array.

Then take that array of hashes, and use [hash slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) to extract the values you want - ordered by key.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#read input data:
my @rows; 

#set record separator to 3 line feeds.     
local $/ = "\n\n\n";
while ( <> ) {
   next unless m/test/;
   #map key-values out of this 'chunk'. 
   my %row = m/(\w+):\s*(\S.*)/g; 
   push @rows, \%row; 
}

#print whole data structure for debugging:
print Dumper \@rows;

#define columns and ordering for output:
my @output_cols = qw ( atest ctest btest ftest gtest );

#iterate rows
foreach my $row ( @rows ) {
    #print fields selected from output_cols. 
   #use a 'hash slice' - look it up in perl docs. 
   print join ";", @{$row}{@output_cols},"\n"
}
```

This gives an output of

```
2;3;8;1;6;
1;5;2;0;5;
```

We use the record separator `$/` to break our input into chunks that *aren't* the "default" of just linefeed.

Which isn't quite the same as you asked, as there's no quotes. If you wanted that though, you could `map`:

```
print join ";", (map { '"'.$_.'"' } @{$row}{@output_cols}),"\n"
```

But I'm not sure that'd be necessary for most `csv` consumers.

Comment: What if the word are not atest btest, etc but let's say risk, test, total and so on... how would I have to change the m/test/ line so it works?

Comment: the `m/test` line is just to catch empty 'blocks', so any keyword. Commenting it out _should_ work but you might get some 'null' lines if you've got anything else in your input file. Otherwise `m/MyValStart/` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks but I am getting Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scanner4.pl line 28, <> chunk 6.
Not shure why

Comment: Probably means a row without all the values present, which will give that error. Check the `Dumper` output (or the printed output) to see if that's what you expect.

Comment: some things are there others are not being read in the Dumpster

Comment: I can only answer based on the sample data that you've given. Works in my test case though, so *shrug*. Maybe post the bits that aren't working in a new question?

Comment: the problem is, that some values expand over multiple rows and nee to be concatenated for the value in the csv

Comment: multiline regex matches are a thing too. You could quite easily match based on blank lines, or lines without `:` in them.